# In Python, how to map multiple item to one function/value?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, data-structures, mapping

Here is the toy example to demonstrate my problem
I have multiple function which will be used exclusively on some of my item

```
def eat_food(item):
    print(f'I ate {item}')

def own_pet(item):
    print(f'I own {item}')

def live_place(item):
    print(f'I live in {item}')
```

Here is the correspoding item

```
animal = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird']
food = ['pizza', 'ham', 'cake']
place = ['Italy', 'USA', 'Malaysia']
```

I want to apply these functions only on the appropriate item something like

```
mapping = {'animal':own_pet,
           'food':eat_food,
           'place':live_place}

random_list = ['cat', 'cake', 'pizza', 'USA']
for item in random_list:
    if item in animal:
        apply_function = 'animal'
    elif item in food:
        apply_function = 'food'
    elif item in place:
        apply_function = 'place'
    mapping[apply_function](item)
```

output:

```
I own cat
I ate cake
I ate pizza
I live in USA
```

The problem is that I need to write if else on every condition and I think it won't scale well if the categories grow. Are there any more sophisciated/pythonic ways to deal with this?

I also don't wanna write out something like this

```
mapping = {'cat':own_pet,
           'dog':own_pet,
           'bird':own_pet,
           'pizza':eat_food,
           ...
            }

for item in random_list:
    mapping[item](item)
```

I'm thinking about something like

```
mapping = {animal:own_pet,
           food:eat_food,
           place:live_place}

# Translate into this
# mapping = {['cat', 'dog', 'bird']:own_pet,
#            ['pizza', 'ham', 'cake']:eat_food,
#            ['Italy', 'USA', 'Malaysia']:live_place}

random_list = ['cat', 'cake', 'pizza', 'USA']
for item in random_list:
    mapping[`***some mysterious technique***`](item)
```

The logic is that "if my item is inside the first key, then apply the first value, and so on" or vice versa "if my item inside the first value, apply the fitst key, and so on"

It doesn't have to be a dictionary either, I have a feeling that there must be something suitable than using dictionary

Answer (score 2):

It can be a dictionary, but the keys could be single words from the lists and values functions. For example:

```py
def eat_food(item):
    print(f"I ate {item}")


def own_pet(item):
    print(f"I own {item}")


def live_place(item):
    print(f"I live in {item}")


animal = ["cat", "dog", "bird"]
food = ["pizza", "ham", "cake"]
place = ["Italy", "USA", "Malaysia"]

mapping = {
    word: func
    for wordlist, func in zip(
        [animal, food, place], [own_pet, eat_food, live_place]
    )
    for word in wordlist
}

random_list = ["cat", "cake", "pizza", "USA", "xxx"]
for value in random_list:
    mapping.get(value, lambda x: None)(value)
```

Prints:

```
I own cat
I ate cake
I ate pizza
I live in USA
```

Comment: Could be a minor typo:  - for wordlist, func in zip( [animals, food, places], `[own_pet, eat_food, live_place]`   Order does make a difference...

Comment: Suggestion - change the `value` to `key`, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way for how to do it.

As soon as :

```
mapping = {animal:own_pet,
           food:eat_food,
           place:live_place}
```

will raise:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

You would better do:

```
mapping = {own_pet:animal,
           eat_food:food,
           live_place:place}
```

Then in order to do what you are looking for, I processed like that:

```
random_list = ["cat", "cake", "pizza", "USA"]
for item in random_list:
    for (thefunction, thelist) in mapping.items():
        if item in thelist:
            thefunction(item)
```